# how to pass props in components?

Tags: reactjs

i'm passing the function in the props

my this code is working fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-northcutt-00xtt?file=/src/App.js

but not when i use as props: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-voice-ysmb2?file=/src/App.js:0-1138
i would like to know where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `{renderInputs()}` in your form.js